# Сохранение переключений между fragmentами android

Tags: java, android

Допустим есть Фрагмент 1, 2 и 3.

Пользователь сначала переходит на 1 фрагмент, затем на 2, потом на третий.
Можно ли реализовать, что при нажатии назад пользователь возвращался на предыдущий фрагмент?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для данного сценария должно хватить addToBackStack() https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно переопределить метод onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```